# Node.js mongoose connect error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have node.js project which contain mongo database. I use mongoose schema. 3 file in project are: index.js, users.js and db.js. when I want to connect mongodb via mongoose, I can't. Here is my code. when it runs it says

> **"error is: TypeError: parseFn is not a function."**

pls help!!

**db.js**

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myDB', { useNewUrlParser:true}).then(
(res) => {
console.log("Success!!.")
}).catch((e) => {console.log("error is: " + e);});
```

**users.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema= new Schema({
id:{type : Number, required: true, unique:true},
username : String,
password : String }, {collection: 'userTB'});

var userS= mongoose.model('userTBL', userSchema);

module.exports=userS;
```

**index.js**

```
...
var db=require('./app_server/models/db');
...
```

Comment: use `.catch(e) { console.log(e) }` and see what the actual error Mongoose is throwing is.

Comment: If this is not enough, you can also try `mongoose.set('debug', true)` before `mongo.connect` so you get a ton of logs.

Comment: when I try "catch(e) { console.log(e) }" as you said, it says "TypeError: parseFn is not a function"

Comment: Post some more adjacent code in context.

Comment: Is your Mongo server running? What is you access `http://localhost:27017` in your browser? Also, what if you remove `{ useNewUrlParser:true}` ?

Comment: @JeremyThille I'm using dig oce VPS. and my code run on server.

Comment: Well, use `curl localhost:27017` then. What about my second question?

Comment: @JeremyThille 1-) my mongo is runing via putty. I can execute mongo command via putty("show dbs etc...). 2-) when I write http://my_vps_ip_addrs:27017 in my browser it says **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**. 3-)when I remove { useNewUrlParser:true} it says **DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.**

Comment: Yes, you SSH into your server using Putty. Now if you `curl localhost:27017` in there, you should get a response from Mongo if it runs. Getting `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` from `my_vps_ip_addrs:27017` is perfectly normal, as Mongo does not listen to the outside world but only on localhost, that's why you have to reach it via Putty. OK so `{ useNewUrlParser:true}` is not the problem

Comment: when I type **curl localhost:27017** on putty console it says 
**It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.**

Comment: OK so everything looks normal. Mongo is running and responding. At this point I have no idea what's wrong :/

Comment: @JeremyThille Thank you for taking the time

Comment: At this point, I'd check MongoDB version, Mongoose version, etc. like, update everything if necessary

Comment: as @JeremyThille said I update my mongodb and mongoose, and problem solved. thanks for everybody

Comment: Oh nice :) Glad you solved it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I guess I faced the same kinda error when I was a newbie in MongoDB. If I'm not wrong this error is because you haven't actually started your local MongoDB server yet. You actually have to start the MongoDB server **manually** to connect to it. The command to start mongo server from the terminal is something like:

```
mongod --dbpath /data/db
```